# beginner xcode swift sprite kit - remove sprite by name crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite

I'm trying to remove some sprites when they hit the bottom. It works if I don't check the name but it removes my background too. When I try to add the name to the `if` it crashes.

```
func checkifbotsreachbottom() {
    for child in self.children {

        if (child.position.y == 0 && child.name == "botone") {

            self.removeChildrenInArray([child])

        }
    }
}
```

This crashes, but if I remove the `child.name` part it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.children` returns `[AnyObject]`.  If you cast it to `[SKNode]` everything should be fine:

```
func checkifbotsreachbottom(){
    for child in self.children as [SKNode] {

        if (child.position.y == 0 && child.name == "botone") {

            self.removeChildrenInArray([child])

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you find my answer addresses your problem, please accept it by ticking the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removeFromParent()

Im using xCode 6.0.1 and it works with this code fine for me.
Performance is constant.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    for child in children{

        if(child.position.y < 0 && child.name == "ship"){
            child.removeFromParent()
        }
    }

}
```